# Running openssl in shell script : Loop run is not working

Tags: shell, ssl, openssl

I want to execute openssl to get the certificate expiry dates for list of sites; Hence want to use looping using shell script. But for few sites its showing the certificate expiry date but; after that, loop is breaking and stopping the execution with out any error.
I tried wait option to be used but no use.

```
filename='site_names.txt'  #this file having list of site names:port in each line    
while read line; do    
    echo "Line No. $n : $line"    
    # this will display certificate validity from and to date/time    
    openssl s_client -connect $line 2> /dev/null |\
        openssl x509 -noout -dates 2>/dev/null 
    n=$((n+1))
done < $filename
```

I execute manually for the sites for which loop is breaking. I observed if takes few seconds(about 5sec) to complete command (ssl connection)

Can you please advise if any other option where shell script executes completely for all sites.

Comment: It might be useful to save stderr instead of throwing it away when you are debugging the problem. Also, please provide at least a minimal input list so that others can reproduce the problem you are having

Comment: have you converted `site_names.txt` from dos to unix format? try `dos2unix site_names.txt` probably thats the issue

Comment: Perhaps you have a `set -e` option somewhere upstream? That will cause the script to abort if it encounters an error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are missing an `echo |` right before the `openssl` command in your loop. If you change that to this:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect $line 2> /dev/null |\
openssl x509 -noout -dates 2>/dev/null
```

You should get it working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `< /dev/null` to the first openssl command since it reads stdin and reads remaining input from the file you are trying to loop through.

```
openssl s_client -connect $line 2> /dev/null < /dev/null |\
    openssl x509 -noout -dates 2>/dev/null
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37168235/1048376

Here is a similar script that I am using:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read URLs and ports from a file (one URL:port per line)
input_file="urls.txt"

# Loop through each URL and port
while IFS=: read -r url port
do
  # Get the certificate dates using openssl
  certificate_dates=$(openssl s_client -servername "$url" -connect 
"$url":"$port" 2>/dev/null < /dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates)

  # Extract the end date from the certificate dates
  start_date=$(echo "$certificate_dates" | awk -F= '/notBefore/{print $2}')
  end_date=$(echo "$certificate_dates" | awk -F= '/notAfter/{print $2}')

  # Print the URL, port, start date, and end date
  echo "URL: $url"
  echo "Port: $port"
  echo "Start Date: $start_date"
  echo "End Date: $end_date"
  echo "---------------------"
done < "$input_file"
```